# How do I yield a pre-unpacked list?

Tags: python, group-by, yield, python-itertools, iterable-unpacking

I have a list that is created within an `itertools.groupby` operation:

```
def yield_unpacked_list():
    for key, grp in itertools.groupby(something_to_groupby, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        subset_of_grp = list(item[2] for item in list(grp))
        yield key, subset_of_grp
```

If, for example, `subset_of_grp` turns out to be `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[5, 6, 7, 8]`:

```
for m in yield_unpacked_list():
    print m
```

would print out:

```
('first_key', [1, 2, 3, 4])
('second_key', [5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Now, going back to my function definition. Obviously the following is a syntax error (the `*` operator):

```
def yield_unpacked_list():
    for key, grp in itertools.groupby(something_to_groupby, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        subset_of_grp = list(item[2] for item in list(grp))
        yield key, *subset_of_grp
```

I want the following result for the **same** `print` loop to be without the `[list]` brackets:

```
('first_key', 1, 2, 3, 4)
('second_key', 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Note that `print` is only for illustrative purposes here. I have other functions that would benefit from the simplified `tuple` structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yield (key,) + tuple(subset_of_grp)`

Answer (score 2):

```
def yield_unpacked_list():
    for key, grp in itertools.groupby(something_to_groupby, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        yield (key,) + tuple(item[2] for item in grp)
```

From the result you want for printing, it's clear that you want to yield a `tuple` -- no idea why you call it an "unpacked list" instead, but, anyway, there you are.  I also removed a couple of calls to `list` that simply served no useful role at all in your code.